# Unable to set manual scaling on a google app engine service

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine

I am unable to set manual scaling on a google app engine service (Previously called module). Using python on app engine.

***app.yaml:***

```
application: xxx-xxxx
version: 2
runtime: python27
module: xxbackend
instance_class: F4
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /taskcontroller\.py
  script: TaskController.app

so on...

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: latest
- name: numpy
  version: "1.6.1"
- name: PIL
  version: latest

inbound_services:
- warmup
```

***xxbackend.yaml:***

```
application: xxx-xxxx
version: uno
module: xxbackend
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
instance_class: B4
manual_scaling:
  instances: 5
```

Even though I have specified instance class and manual scaling settings in xxbackend.yaml, the xxbackend instances are still autoscaled. Can someone point out where I am going wrong?

Comment: I just used gcloud SDK v123.0.0 from the command line and it works for me. How are you deploying your yaml? Though you'll have to remove application & version from the yaml, as they're no longer supported. I deployed with the command `gcloud app deploy xbackend.yaml --version uno` and it works fine.

Comment: @atimothee I had been trying to deploy using the Launcher release: "1.9.40". GAEfan's suggestions did work fine. I haven't yet moved to gcloud deployment yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the same `module:` name is both yamls.  `app.yaml` should not specify a module, so it uses the `default` module.  So remove `module: xxbackend` from `app.yaml`.  Otherwise, you are overriding the expected config.

Then, when you deploy, use a command like:

`appcfg.py update app.yaml xxbackend.yaml`

That deploys both updated yaml files.